# How to increase the height or width(through scrolling) for InkCanvas when the user Ink near the end?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal, inkcanvas

I want to increase the height or width(through scrolling) of `InkCanvas` when the user Ink near the end of the `InkCanvas` Like OneNote.

**Solution Tried:**

1. I tried `ScrollViewer` for `InkCanvas` but It didn't work
2. I thought of re-styling it but I can't find the `InkCanvas` in generic.xaml

**Here is my code for InkCanvas:**

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
    <Grid>
        <InkCanvas Name="PATH_INK_CANVAS" Canvas.ZIndex="-1"/>
        <RichEditBox Name="PATH_RICH_EDIT_BOX" Canvas.ZIndex="0" PlaceholderText="Input Text" Style="{StaticResource RichEditBoxStyle}"/>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should find the Bound of Ink in `InkCanvas` and compare it with ActualSize of the `InkCanvas` then increase the `InkCanvas` if we need. It can be done using below code.

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    PATH_INK_CANVAS.InkPresenter.StrokeInput.StrokeEnded += StrokeInput_StrokeEndedAsync;
}

private async void StrokeInput_StrokeEndedAsync(InkStrokeInput sender, PointerEventArgs args)
{
    await Task.Delay(100);

    var XBound = PATH_INK_CANVAS.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.BoundingRect.Bottom;
    if (XBound > PATH_INK_CANVAS.ActualHeight - 400)
        PATH_INK_CANVAS.Height = XBound + 400;

    var YBound = PATH_INK_CANVAS.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.BoundingRect.Right;
    if (YBound > PATH_INK_CANVAS.ActualWidth - 400)
        PATH_INK_CANVAS.Width = YBound + 400;
}
```